# How to generate byte array from a pdf? ( iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, pdf, arrays

I have generated a pdf in documents directory in iPhone. Now I want to generate byte array from this pdf. Here is my code:

```
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];        
    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

NSData* pdfData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Then What to do?
Any help?  Thanks....

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `NSData`? See the `bytes` method.

Comment: [pdfData bytes] will create the byte array? How to print the byte array?

Comment: No. The data is loaded into the `NSData` object. The `bytes` method simply gives you access to the data loaded into the `NSData` object. What do you really want to do with the bytes? If you just want to log the data, then log the `pdfData` object: `NSLog(@"data = %@", pdfData);`

Comment: Actually I need to generate a byte array from this pdfdata to send it to webservice. the webservice will receive only byte array of this pdfdata.